# LiveData Observer not called when using postponeEnterTransition

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, shared-element-transition

I'm following the documentation here to start a transition after fetching data: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#recyclerview

The viewModel code is invoked and runs successfully, but the observer is never called when `postponeEnterTransition` is used. If I remove `postponeEnterTransition`, then the observer is called.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    postponeEnterTransition()

    homeViewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        // TODO: set data on adapter

        startPostponedEnterTransition()
    }

    homeViewModel.fetchData()
}
```

And here is my view model code:

```
class HomeViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    val loading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    }

    val data: MutableLiveData<List<Data>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Data>>()
    }

    fun fetchData() {
        loading.postValue(true)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.fetchData()
            result?.let {
                when(it) {
                    is Result.Success -> data.postValue(it.data)
                    is Result.Error -> "" // TODO: Handle error
                }
            }
            loading.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe move `postponeEnterTransition()` to `onCreate()`?

Comment: Never come across such situation but, as far as I know, the observing on livedata will work AFTER your activity is in the RESUME state. I suggest on changing the trigger for startPostponedEnterTransition().

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I ended up moving `startPostponedEnterTransition` out of the observer and placed it right after `postponeEnterTransition` in a post: `home_recycler_view.post { startPostponedEnterTransition() }` and when I return to the fragment, the observer responds before the post code executes.
I'm still not sure why it doesn't work to put it inside the observer, but seems it's not necessary in my case.

Comment: faced same issue